# Saving tests in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, testing

I'm running VS 2012 on Windows 7 and have run several tests using the native Test Explorer (all code is in C#). Some tests passed, some failed and some were skipped. How do I save the test results so I can retrieve them later and how do I compile (or export) a list of tests that passed so I can send these to my manager? I was unable to find answers to these online. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the **Export Test Run Results**-feature in Visual Studio.

Comment: Maybe this is what you are looking for: http://trx2html.codeplex.com/. Im not sure if it works for VS 2012.

Comment: I wasn't able to find the "Export Test Run Results" feature.